# Angular: data retrieved from API only appears when app is first time launched

Tags: database, angular, routes

I just have two components, and the app is connected to firebase (firestore). The data called in ngOnInit disappears when I navigate and only appears again if I insert a Post or a User (forms).Why? Can someone help me out?

The routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "admin",
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];
```

The Service

```
itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  items: Observable<Post[]>;
  itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Post>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {


    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts', ref =>
      ref.orderBy('date', 'desc')
    );

    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }
```

Its Component and the subscription

```
 private postService: PostsService,

  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getItems().subscribe(data => {
      this.postInput = data;
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create posts property in your service.
Then subscribe to your observable in your service, set posts to what u get from firebase.
Also dont write your code inside constructor but wrap in in a function and use it in OnInit in apropriate component. And lastly create a Subject send with it the current posts and subscribe to them in onInit inside desired components

```
posts = Post[]
postsChanged = new Subject<Post[]>()  

getItems(){
    this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        return {
          id: a.payload.doc.id,
          ...a.payload.doc.data() 
        }
      }).subscribe(posts => {
           this.posts = posts
           this.postsChanged.next([...this.posts])
        })
   }
```

Comment: it does not work, I get `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Post[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.` when hovering this.items wich are redish

Comment: can you please edit your answer? Im getting puzzled now

Comment: You probably assigned the Subscription to your items property, dont do that. When you look at my code, you can see that i am not assigning it to anything just subscribing right awaz

Comment: I fixed the bug with your hints. I wrapped code in a function getID(), i've called it in service constructor and in the component and now it works

Comment: if you want to post the correct answer, the credit is yours

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kase44 hints i managed to find a solution: wrapped the capture of the ID in a function, called it in the service constructor and in the ngOnInit():

The Service

```
export class UsersService {

  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Users>;
  userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Users>;
  users: Observable<Users[]>;
  user: Observable<Users>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection('employees', ref =>
      ref.orderBy('name', 'asc')
    );
this.getUserID();

  }

getUserID(){
  this.users = this.usersCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Users;
      data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return data;
    });
  });
}
```

And the component:

```
     ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.emp = data;

    });
    this.userService.getUserID();
  }
```